# Convolution of squares / boxcars in functional form

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution, sinc

$$
\Pi(t/A) * \Pi(t/B)
$$

where

$$
\Pi(t) = 
\begin{cases}
1,\ -1/2 \leq t \leq 1/2 \\
0,\ \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

How to compute? Derivation/steps optional but welcome.

**Note**: I'm aware of classic and simple solutions to this problem, but my context is [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/83323/50076), where $C, D$ can be any real non-zero, and the *result should not include conditionals* (but functions that say the same thing are allowed).

Comment: If I were you, I would adjust the definition of $\Pi(\cdot)$ a little.

Comment: I follow a [standard definition](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Rectangular_function), where treatment of discontinuity doesn't change $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Take a look at [this trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1828854/339790)

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Great find! This question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Not quite a find because the answer was written by me ;-) Since it is on Math SE, can one close this one as a duplicate?

Answer (score 4):

Up till Revision 3 of the OP's question, the function $\Pi(t)$ was defined as a centered rectangular pulse of duration $2$, or effectively, $\operatorname{rect}\left(\frac t2\right)$. The definition has now been changed so that now $\Pi(t)$ is $\operatorname{rect}\left(t\right)$, making my comments on the OP's original self-answer no longer relevant. In my opinion, the OP's self-answer is still unduly cumbersome and so here goes.

Let $\Pi(t)$ be defined as $\operatorname{rect}\left(t\right)$, a unit-height pulse of unit duration, centered at the origin. It is straightforward to verify that
$$\left(\Pi * \Pi\right)(t) = \begin{cases}1-|t|, & -1 < t < 1,\\
 0, & |t| \geq  1 \end{cases}$$
which is the familiar triangle function $\operatorname{tri}(t)$ that increases linearly (with slope $1$) from value $0$ at $t=-1$ to value $1$ at $t=0$ and then decreases linearly (with slope  $-1$) to value $0$ at $t=1$.

The OP wishes to find a simple expression for $\left(\Pi_A * \Pi_B\right)(t)$ where $\Pi_A(t)$ and $\Pi_B(t)$ denote $\Pi\left(\frac tA\right)$ and $\Pi\left(\frac tB\right)$ respectively for *arbitrary* nonzero real numbers $A$ and $B$, and promises to excoriate all answers that do not consider the possibility that  and/or  might be negative. What the OP fails to realize is that sinc $\operatorname{rect}(t)$ is an even function of $t$, $\Pi_A(t) = \Pi_{-A}(t)$ and $\Pi_B(t) = \Pi_{-B}(t)$. Thus, without loss of any generality, we can write
$$\left(\Pi_A * \Pi_B\right)(t) = \left(\Pi_{|A|} * \Pi_{|B|}\right)(t)$$
which is a trapezoidal function increasing linearly (slope $1$) from value $0$ at
$$t= -\left.\left.\frac 12\right(\max(|A|,|B|)+\min(|A|,|B|)\right)=-\frac 12\big(|A|+|B|\big) $$ to value $\min(|A|,|B|) = \big|\,|A|-|B|\,\big|$ at
$$t =  -\left.\left.\frac 12\right(\max(|A|,|B|)-\min(|A|,|B|)\right) = -\frac 12 \big(|A-B|\big),$$ then remaining at constant at $\min(|A|,|B|)$ till
$$t = + \left.\left.\frac 12\right(\max(|A|,|B|-\min(|A|,|B|)\right)= +\frac 12 \big(|A-B|\big),$$ at which point it starts decreasing linearly with slope $-1$ till it reaches $0$ again at
$$t = +\left.\left.\frac 12\right(\max(|A|,|B|)+\min(|A|,|B|)\right)= +\frac 12\big(|A|+|B|\big).$$ This is indeed a function that would be described by a multiline formula, which doesn't work for OP, and so let's write it in in terms of the triangle function. Note that for any $C > 0$, the convolution of $\Pi_C(t)$ with itself is
$$(\Pi_C * \Pi_C)(t) = C\cdot\operatorname{tri}\left(\frac tC\right)$$
and it is straightforward to verify that $\left(\Pi_{A} * \Pi_{B}\right)(t)$ is the *difference* of two triangle functions, namely
\begin{align}\left(\Pi_{A} * \Pi_{B}\right)(t) &= \bigr(|A|+|B|\bigr)\operatorname{tri}\bigg(\frac{t}{|A|+|B|}\bigg)-\bigr(|A -B|\bigr)
\operatorname{tri}\bigg(\frac{t}{|A-B|}\bigg)\tag{1}
\end{align}
or, more prolixly,
\begin{align}
\left(\Pi_{A} * \Pi_{B}\right)(t)&= \bigr(\max(|A|,|B|)+\min(|A|,|B|)\bigr)\operatorname{tri}\bigg(\frac{t}{\max(|A|,|B|)+\min(|A|,|B|)}\bigg)\\
&\hspace{.1in}-\bigr(\max(|A|,|B|)-\min(|A|,|B|)\bigr)\operatorname{tri}\left(\frac{t}{\max(|A|,|B|)-\min(|A|,|B|)}\right).\tag{2}
\end{align}

Comment: Ok, back to being insufferable.

Comment: Yes indeed.  I have restored my answer to what it said before you defaced it by adding stuff that I disagree with,

Answer (score 2):

I'll give this a whirl. Let's define the causal rectangular function $R(t)$ to be

$$ R(t) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 < t < 1 \\
0 &  else\\
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Let's find $Y(t) =  R(t/C)  * R(t/D)$, where $*$ denotes convolution. Without loss of generality we can assume that $C \leq D$ and we simply get

$$ R(t) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
t & 0 < t <= C \\
C & C <= t <= D \\
t-C & D <= t <= D+C \\
0 &  else\\
\end{matrix}\right.$$

In order to find the answer to the original question as asked we can use the relationships

$$\Pi(t) = R((t+1)/2), \\ R(t) = \Pi(2t-1)$$

Comment: _"without loss of generality"_ isn't true for this question's purpose, also this answer assumes positive $C, D$. It also uses conditionals, which cannot readily be plugged into other calculations. I'm well-aware of classic solutions to this problem, but my context is [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/83323/50076), where $C, D$ can be any real non-zero. I should've been more explicit in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Apply convolution theorem:
$$
|A||B|\ \mathrm{sinc}(A\omega/2) \ \mathrm{sinc}(B\omega/2) 
$$

[WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=fourier+transform+sinc%28A%2F2*t%29+*+sinc%28B%2F2*t%29) gives for $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$, disregarding constants,

$$
\begin{align}
&& (A + B - 2t) \ \mathrm{sgn}(A + B - 2t)    & - (A - B + 2t)\ \mathrm{sgn}(A/2 - B/2 + t) + \\
&& (A - B - 2t)\ \mathrm{sgn}(-A/2 + B/2 + t) & + (A + B + 2t)\ \mathrm{sgn}(A/2 + B/2 + t) 
\end{align}
$$

With constants, we multiply all above by

$$
\frac{|A||B|}{4AB} = \frac{1}{4}\mathrm{sgn}(AB)
$$

Plotted in [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/v2nvnav3zw). This is the primary solution.

#### Validating

Comparing sampling the function against FFT convolution:

```py
def formula(t, A, B):
    s = lambda x: np.sign(x)
    p, m = A + B, A - B
    
    o0 = (p - 2*t)*s(p - 2*t)  - (m + 2*t)*s(m/2 + t)
    o1 = (m - 2*t)*s(-m/2 + t) + (p + 2*t)*s(p/2 + t)
    return (o0 + o1) * (1/4)*s(A*B)
```

Now for discrete and comparing:

```py
N, A, B = 4096, 10, 4
t = np.linspace(-A*B, A*B, N, 0)  # span long enough interval, A*B

boxcar = lambda A: ((t >= -A/2) * (t <= A/2)).astype(int)
x0, x1 = boxcar(A), boxcar(B)

o_fftconv = fft_conv_and_center(x0, x1) * abs(2 * A * B) / N
o_formula = out(t, A, B)
```

[Full code](https://pastebin.com/W5G9S1mX) -- we also need to scale the discrete result by $2|AB|/N$, and have a sufficiently high $N$ (something with bandlimiting maybe?). Result:

[image]

Good enough for me.

#### Time-domain derivation

Did this first but then scrapped because the expression in terms of $A, B$ is too complicated. **This isn't the primary solution, only an alt demo.**

Total support is $T=A + B$, of which the flattop part is $T_\text{top}=\max(A, B) - \min(A, B)$, all centered at $x= c = a + b$ (if we did $\Pi(t/A - a) ...$), and let $T_\text{ramp} = T - T_\text{top}$. We have

[image]

which is, and let us define "ramp flat ramp",

$$
\begin{align}
RFR^{*}(T, T_\text{top}, T_\text{ramp}, c) = \ 
& r(t - (c - T/2))\ - \\
& r(t - (c - T/2 + T_\text{ramp}/2))\ - \\
& r(t - (c - T/2 + T_\text{ramp}/2 + T_\text{top}))\ + \\
& r(t - (c - T/2 + T_\text{ramp} + T_\text{top}))
\end{align}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}
RFR(A, B, a, b) = 
RFR^{*}(
& A + B, \max(A, B) - \min(A, B), \\
& A + B - \max(A, B) + \min(A, B), a + b
)
\end{align}
$$

Then flattop's value (hence output max) is

$$
\begin{align}
T_\text{ramp}/2 
&= \frac{1}{2}[A + B - \max(A, B) + \min(A, B)] \\
&= \min(A, B)
\end{align}
$$

We also have $\max(A, B) - \min(A, B) = |A - B|$ (for real $A, B$), and we can simplify to

$$
RFR^{*}(A + B, |A - B|, 2 \min (A, B), a + b)
$$

**NOTES:**

- $A$ and $B$ are assumed to be non-negative (only in this solution)
- $*$ isn't complex conjugation (as is seen from the first invocation)
- $r(t) = (t \geq 0)$, [ramp](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Ramp_function)

Comment: That seems needless complicated and convoluted (pun a little intended).  The convolution of two rectangles of width A and B is a symmetric trapeze. Assuming A is shorter, the length of the slopes is A and the length of the flat part is B-A.. For $A=B$ you get a triangle since $B-A = 0$. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @Hilmar But writing it mathematically won't be any simpler than the above result? Also for discrete we can derive the answer exactly and easier, yes.

Comment: "simple" is a matter of personal preference, I guess. In my personal opinion, my description can be easily turned into a simple piece-wise definition which seems (to me) easier to use for subsequent operations like convolution, integration, differentiation, etc. But that's just me. Also, your result appears to be wrong: the magnitude of the flat part should be $min(A,B)$, i.e. 3 in your case. Not sure how something related to $\pi$ snuck in there. That's another advantage of a verbal description: you can use it to double check the math.

Comment: @Hilmar I agree the derivation is simpler, but the final expression in terms of $A, B$ not so much. Thanks for pointing out $\min(A, B)$, think I missed the $1/(2\pi)$ in FT inversion, fixed.

Comment: This answer has too many incorrect statements in its details. The function $\Pi (t)$ is related to $\operatorname{rect}(t)$ as $\Pi(t) =\operatorname{rect}\left(\frac t2\right)$ and so the convolution under consideration is of two even rectangular pulses of durations $2A$ and $2B$ respectively, _not_ $A$ and $B$ as both the OP and @Hilmar are assuming.  Thus, their convolution is a trapezium of base $2A+2B$ and altitude $2\min\{A,B\}$, while the flat top is of duration $2*(\max\{A,B\}-\min\{A,B\})$.  This accounts for the $t \to t/2$ phenomenon encountered by the OP.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Right, thanks. Any other statements ("too many")?

Comment: When the only tool you have in your toolbox is a hammer, everything looks like a nail. The FFT is _not_ the tool to use in solving this problem; the signals are nonzero for $t<0$, while the FFT can deal only with causal signals. So you have to drag the signals to the positive axis, and then re-drag the answer back to put it in its proper place. The changing definitions don't help either.  There is a reference to a related question and parameters $C$ and $D$ therein, but looking at the related question shows a complete absence of $C$ and $D$.  -1 for the answer and -1 on the question too.

Comment: @DilipSarwate This Q&A is about the convolution in question without constraining signs of $A, B$ and without using conditionals, to which I have provided two solutions, and optional numeric verification, so I don't see any relevance of your comments in justifying the votes. You also confuse my notation with Hilmar's, no $C, D$. You're welcome to show how my answer is wrong.

Comment: Also the FFT requires no such thing. What you may be describing is akin to "DFT assumes input is periodic" i.e. DFT<->DTFT, but it's also directly at odds with it... frankly I've no clue what you intend and it's the first time I hear it.

Comment: I will remove my downvote if you edit your answer once again to specify clearly what  the function $r(\cdot)$ is, and also state explicitly that the $*$ in your $RFR^*$ function does not mean complex conjugate of the $RFR$ fun action, and that your time-domain derivation is valid regardless of the signs of $A$ and $B$, assuming, of course, that these statements are true. You say that $A+B$ is the length of the base of the trapezoid which is suspect when $A$ and $B$ have opposite or negative signs.  Did you mean to write $|A|+|B|$ as the length of the base?

Comment: @DilipSarwate The other stuff's a bit redundant but good point on signs - one could infer it from $T = A + B$ but explicit is better.